# How to check which Web Front End server is user request hitting

Tags: sharepoint-server

How to find a request is going to a particular web front end server?

Let us assume, we have four web front end servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There couple of ways to check this.

1. Using the http response as mentioned in other reply
2. Or use a image to track the wfe

   - you have to create an image with wfe name on it, one for each server
   - now place the image in hive folder( template\images).
   - do the same on all wfe with their named image
   - now you have to edit the page of your site collection and add that image in it
   - now every time user browse the page, whoever server the users request get his image locally from hive folder
3. Another way is, if you want doing the testing. Then shut the servers and keep one alive and test it
   http://geekswithblogs.net/kjones/archive/2010/10/29/142510.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could add custom HTTP Response Header for each server in IIS. So in your case it could be "WFE01", "WFE02", "WFE03", "WFE04".

After that you can use fiddler to see which WFE you hit when accessing SharePoint using Fiddler and checking the Response Headers sent back to you.

Here's the article that goes into detail of how to do so:

[How to Find Which SharePoint Server You are Hitting](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/09/how-to-find-which-sharepoint-server-is-serving-to-you.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have a feature deployed to the farm that exposes a new drop down in the Action menu that shows what WFE your attached to:

Code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls

Public Class ConnectedWFE
    Inherits WebControl

    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
        Me.EnsureChildControls()
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub CreateChildControls()
        Dim Server As New MenuItemTemplate([String].Format("Connected to: {0}", HttpContext.Current.Server.MachineName), "/_layouts/15/images/centraladmin_systemsettings_servers_32x32.png")
        Server.Description = "The WFE you are connected to."
        Controls.Add(Server)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Element.xml

```
xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"
Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/"
    CustomAction Id="{c3b7b1af-7133-4a4d-9e25-029b284aa20f}"
                    GroupId="PersonalActions"
                    Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
                    Sequence="1000"
                    Title="Connected WFE"
                    ControlAssembly="Company.SP.ER.ConnectedWFE, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1e2ae4dfed6f6f75"
                    ControlClass="Company.SP.ER.ConnectedWFE.ConnectedWFE" 
        <UrlAction Url=""
    CustomAction
Elements
```